# How do I make a javascript div open on load but hide when clicking on another div link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

You can see my page sample here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24791073/TheAmericanWorker/index5.html. I am trying to load the MEC div, then close it when clicking on another link such as Minimum Value Plans in the top bar. I tried just having it "display:block" instead of "display:none", but that doesn't allow me to close it.

Here is the javascript code up top I am using.

```
lastone = 'empty';

function showIt(lyr) {
    if (lastone != 'empty') lastone.style.display = 'none';
    lastone = document.getElementById(lyr);
    lastone.style.display = 'block';
};

function hideIt(lyr) {
    if (lastone != 'empty') lastone.style.display = 'block';
    lastone = document.getElementById(lyr);
    lastone.style.display = 'none';
}
```

and a sample of the link code:

```
<a href="JavaScript:"showonlyone";" onClick="showIt('MEC')" class="homeheader">MEC Plans 

<div id="MEC" style="display:none;">
    <p class=textwhheader>MEC Plans allow employers to offer qualifying coverage to their employees on a self-funded basis, which satisfies the individual mandate.
</p> 
<br>

    <a id='register'

                                class="btn red pure-button pure-button-primary"

                                style="font-size:13.33px; font-weight:700; line-height:26px; height:24px;vertical-align:middle;"

                                href='mecplans.html'

                                title="Click here to learn more.">

                                Learn More

                            </a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: please tidy up your html code, im sure you will find the problem yourself when your code is clean and tidy.

Comment: I cleaned up the code and see your edits. However, that works to hide the "display:block", but now when I click on any of the other divs, it only hides the "display:block" and none of the "display:none", which causes the other divs to remain open.

Comment: i only edited and tidied up your javascript code. your html is contains severe errors. for example, the attribute `href="JavaScript:"showonlyone";"` is completely invalid.

Comment: make `lastone = document.getElementById('MEC');` instead of `empty`, as you are displaying MEC one as default. OR you can call `showIt('MEC')` on page load.

Comment: Here is a way I would have done it. http://jsfiddle.net/nqu46a34/9/

Comment: Thanks for the input.... Ankit, that doesn't seem to work....

Comment: David, your link didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinJackson Have you solved this? Do you still need help? The link in your question looks like it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Since my link was not working, hope this is what you were after:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="first option" onClick="toggleDiv('myDiv1');">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="first option" onClick="toggleDiv('myDiv2');">Option 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="myDiv1">
    <span>Some data here</span>
</div>
<div id="myDiv2" style="display:none">
    <span>Div 2 data</span>
</div>

var currentActiveDiv = 'myDiv1';

toggleDiv = function(id){
    var domElement = document.getElementById(id);

    if (currentActiveDiv && currentActiveDiv !== id){
        var elementToHide = document.getElementById(currentActiveDiv);
        elementToHide.style.display = 'none';
    }

    domElement.style.display = 'block';
    currentActiveDiv = id;
};
```

Regards,
David.

Comment: Thanks David. That helped clean up my code. Now the only thing I need help on is making myDiv1 be open on page load, and then hidden when I click on any other DIV. I can mark it as block instead of none, but then it stays open no matter what I click on. Thoughts?

Comment: Updated the answer with a document load where I am setting myDiv1 visible.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't cause myDiv1 to load and open upon initially opening the page. Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Could you see if the code was triggered when your page loaded? Another option is to make myDiv1 style="display:block" by default. And add the id for the div in the variable that is tracking which div is open. Look at updated code.

Comment: Thanks to all, I think I am all set.